# Wrong Url Mapping For Jsp File

Tags: xml, jsp, web-applications

I've done a mapping for my jsp but it don't work!

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/web/Pages/Index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When i run Index.jsp file my browser shows me this: */Pages/Index.jsp*
And if i try to use this Url: */Index.jsp* i'm fall into 404 error!

Comment: So, the URL /Pages/Index.jsp works fine? Why do you think /Index.jsp should work as well?

Comment: Because i would to hide the real arrangement and show only the name of Jsp in URL bar. Is it possible?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Why do you declare a servlet with the jsp-file /web/Pages/Index.jsp if the file is actually /Pages/Index.jsp? And why do you try the URL /Index.jsp if the servlet mapping has the url pattern /Index?

Comment: I'm sorry for my error. Now i declare "/Pages/Index.jsp", i didn't read a missing jspfile in the log. Thanks for your help, now in my log file there are not errors. But if i try "/Index" the browser shows me a 404 error.